# Using arrow keys to scroll while editing a cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, horizontal-scrolling

I have a datagrid in my WPF / C# application, that has rows that stretch far beyond the visible fix-sized window.

```
<DataGrid  Height="470" Width="800" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" x:Name="DgrReadWrite"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    CellEditEnding="DgrReadWrite_CellEditEnding" 
    CurrentCellChanged="DgrReadWrite_CurrentCellChanged"/>
```

When the user double clicks and edits a cell of this datagrid with a lot of text in it, the cursor can move off-window. When you move into that territory (with the arrow keys, for example), you need to drag the scrollbar with the mouse to see where the editing is happening again.

Is there a way to automatically scroll somehow? I haven't seen anything for scrolling while in edit mode...

Answer (score 0):

`DataGrid` will scroll automatically while typing, if you remove constant `Width` and `Height`.